# Найти количество нулевых елементов и сумму елементов меньших 1 и больших 0

Tags: c++

Дано файл действительных чисел a.txt Найти количество нулевых элементов и сумму
элементов меньших 1 и больших 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    ifstream file("a.txt");

    int num = 0;

    while(file)
    {
        string str;
        getline(file, str);

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            if(str[i] != '\0')
            {
                if(str[i] == '0') num++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Количество '0' в строке = " << num << "." << endl;

    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Всё что смог написать, а дальше не получается сделать поиск элементов меньших 1 и больших 0.
P.S. Пользователь сам вводит числа в файл "a.txt".

Comment: Да в общем то таким же способом, как и количество нулевых.

Comment: нет, вы не правильно делаете, Если в  строке написано например  это: "0.34, 0  0.87, 0,  0.3,  0  0     0 " то ваша программа выдаст количество нулей для этой строки равен 1

Comment: Непонятно, что искать - количество символов `0`, или чисел 0? Если чисел - то работайте примерно `for(double x; file >> x; )` - и обрабатывайте себе числа `x`...

Comment: спасибо, подсказали как сделать) всё получилось.